# How can I tell mathematica to generate an histogram from nominal data?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

If I write:

```
Histogram[{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}]
```

I get a nice histogram chart

but if I write

```
Histogram[{"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"}]
```

I get an **empty** chart!!

How can I tell mathematica to generate an histogram from **nominal** data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
data = {"A", "A", "B", "B", "B"};

elements = DeleteDuplicates[data];

rep = MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, elements];

Histogram[data /. rep, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
 ChartLegends -> elements]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**EDIT**: Incorporating @Simon Wood´s splendid suggestion (we learn that the legend is a plain `Column`, which should be considered a good thing):

Bigger sorted input with monster legend. Notice: Bin widths other than one mess this up somewhat...

```
data = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], 1000] // Sort;
elements = DeleteDuplicates[data];
rep = MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, elements];

Histogram[data /. rep, Length[elements], ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  ChartLegends -> Placed[elements, Right]] /. 
 Column[x_] :> Grid[Partition[x, 4, 4, {1, 1}, {}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now for some fun:

```
data = Characters[ExampleData[{"Text", "FaustI"}]] // Sort;
elements = DeleteDuplicates[data];
rep = MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, elements];

Histogram[data /. rep, Length[elements], ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  ChartLegends -> Placed[elements, Right]] /. 
 Column[x_] :> Grid[Partition[x, 8, 8, {1, 1}, {}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ToDo: modify the ticks accordingly.

Comment: For the legend try `Histogram[...] /. Column[x_] :> Grid[Partition[x, 4, 4, {1, 1}, {}]]`

Answer (score 21):

One posibility is to use `Tally` with `BarChart`.

For example:

```
hist = Tally[{"A", "A", "B", "B", "B"}];
BarChart[hist[[All, 2]], ChartLabels -> hist[[All, 1]]]
```

[image: bar chart]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a variation that works with multiple data sets:

**BarChart: pure categorical variables**

```
 ClearAll[mapCount]
 mapCount[dataset_] := 
 Map[Function[{elem}, {elem, Count[#, elem]}], Union @@ dataset] & /@ dataset


 data2 = {{"A", "A", "B", "B", "B"}, {"A", "A", "A", "A", "B","B"},
  {"A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "B"}};
 bcdatasets = Last /@ # & /@ mapCount[data2];
 bclabels = Union @@ data2;
 BarChart[bcdatasets, ChartLabels -> bclabels]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Tally` on the sorted data sets with `Padright`:

```
BarChart[Last /@ # & /@ PadRight[Tally /@ Sort /@ data2], ChartLabels -> bclabels]
```

gives the same result.

**Histogram: ordered categorical variables:**

```
histdata = ArrayComponents[data2];
histlabels = MapIndexed[{First@#2 + .5, #1} &, Union @@ data2];


Column[Row[{Histogram[histdata, Automatic, #,
  Ticks -> {histlabels, Automatic},
  ChartLayout -> "Overlapped", PlotLabel -> # <> " - Overlapped", 
  ImageSize -> 200], Spacer[15],
 Histogram[histdata, Automatic, #,
  Ticks -> {histlabels, Automatic},
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked", PlotLabel -> # <> " - Stacked", 
  ImageSize -> 200]}] & /@
 {"Count", "Probability", "PDF", "CumulativeCount", "CDF", "SF"}]
```

[image]