# How can I plot the frequency of list items?

Tags: plotting

How can I plot the frequency of list items such as?:
`{62, 62, 62, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 66, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100}`

Also, would it be possible to have the list replace the item with a name? For example, instead of showing that 62 appears 3 times, show that "Joe" has 3 matches in the list?

*I apologize if this is a trivial matter; I've been searching for a few days.*

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(9801)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9801)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data1 = {62, 62, 62, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 66, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 
   82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91,
    91, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100};

names = {62 -> "Joe", 64 -> "Sharon", 66 -> "Bill",
   67 -> "Kelly", 82 -> "Jim", 91 -> "Sue",
   94 -> "Mike", 95 -> "Alice", 100 -> "Bob"};

freq1 = Tally[data1]
```

> {{62, 3}, {64, 6}, {66, 4}, {67, 2}, {82, 12}, {91, 6}, {94, 1}, {95, 
>   4}, {100, 6}}

```
ListPlot[freq1, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

```
data2 = data1 /. names;

freq2 = Tally[data2]
```

> {{"Joe", 3}, {"Sharon", 6}, {"Bill", 4}, {"Kelly", 2}, {"Jim",    12},
>   {"Sue", 6}, {"Mike", 1}, {"Alice", 4}, {"Bob", 6}}

```
StringForm["`1` has `2` matches", ##] & @@@ freq2
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend that you remove the line `freq2 = freq1 /. names` as this could easily lead to error as it will replaces counts as well as items.  +1 however since you give the better way immediately below.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Modified per your recommendation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using:

```
data1 = {62, 62, 62, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 66, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 
   82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91,
    91, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100};

names = {62 -> "Joe", 64 -> "Sharon", 66 -> "Bill", 67 -> "Kelly", 
   82 -> "Jim", 91 -> "Sue", 94 -> "Mike", 95 -> "Alice", 
   100 -> "Bob"};
```

You can use`BarChart`:

```
BarChart[Labeled[#2, #1 /. names] & @@@ Tally[data1]]
```

[image]

Or

```
Needs["StatisticalPlots`"]
ParetoPlot[data1, ChartLabels -> (SortBy[Tally[data1], -#[[2]]&][[All, 1]]/. names), 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
     Panel[NumberForm[N@#1, 2], FrameMargins -> 0], Above] &)]
```

[image]

You can use `StringTemplate` for the textual aim,e.g.

```
s = StringTemplate["<*`1`/.names*> has `2` matches.\n"];
StringJoin @@ (TemplateApply[s, #] & /@ Tally[data1])
```

produces:

Joe has 3 matches.
Sharon has 6 matches.
Bill has 4 matches.
Kelly has 2 matches.
Jim has 12 matches.
Sue has 6 matches.
Mike has 1 matches.
Alice has 4 matches.
Bob has 6 matches.

Answer (score 2):

For the plotting part of your question:

```
ListPlot[Tally[lst], Filling -> Axis]
```