# Getting the number of frequency in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to know how to make a tally board in a specific data appear in a list. E.G.

```
n ={1,2,1,4,3,1,4,5,3,2,4,5,6,3,4,2,2,5,2}
```

and get

```
Case        1  2  3  4  5  6  n
Frequency   3  5  3  4  3  1  19
```

Hoping for an answer thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60185/how-can-i-plot-the-frequency-of-list-items

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think the OP requested here a specific formatting that includes not only `Tally` but also sorting,  `TableHeadings`, calculate `Length` of the dataset and probably `TableForm` or similar. There is significant overlap, but its not an exacte duplicate

Comment: To @jobert I would recommend to take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and understand what is a [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). Also you could  [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make it more specific and a [better question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @rhermans While I saw that part as incidental since you chose to focus on it I shall reopen the question.

Comment: Related: [(9801)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9801/121), [(30859)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30859/121)

Comment: @jobert, [you should read what to do now that your question was answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

Your data:

```
n ={1,2,1,4,3,1,4,5,3,2,4,5,6,3,4,2,2,5,2};
```

To get the [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) list:

```
Tally[n]
```

To format it into a *Tally Table* we use [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html):

```
Block[{t = Tally[n]},
 TableForm[t, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Number", "Frequency"}}]
]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

It happens now that its not sorted, nor in the orientation you wanted so we use [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html),  [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html) and [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html). Also include the total number of cases at the end

```
Block[
 {tally, table},
 tally = SortBy[Tally[n], First];
 table = Transpose@Append[tally, {"n", Length@n}];
 TableForm[table, TableHeadings -> {{"Case", "Frequency"}, None}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is the format the OP requested.

Answer (score 6):

There is also ... `EmpiricalDistribution`:

```
lst = {1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2};

dist = EmpiricalDistribution[lst];
tally = {#["Domain"], #["SampleSize"] #["Weights"]} &[dist];
Transpose[tally] == Sort@Tally[lst]
(* True *)
TableForm[tally, TableHeadings -> {{"values", "frequency"}, None}]
```

[image]

```
tally2 = {Join @@ {#["Domain"], {"nobs"}},
    Join @@ {#["SampleSize"] #["Weights"], {#["SampleSize"]}}} &[dist]; 
TableForm[tally2, TableHeadings -> {{"values", "frequency"}, None}, 
          TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: nice use of `EmpiricalDistribution`

Answer (score 3):

`Tally` is the function you need.

```
n = {1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2};
Tally[n]
```

produces:

```
{{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 4}, {3, 3}, {5, 3}, {6, 1}}
```

You can use `Count` for a specific element. Other ways to tally:

```
{#,Count[n, #]} & /@ Union[n]
```

Or

```
Last@Reap[Sow[1, #] & /@ n, _, {#1, Total@#2} &]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CountsBy[n, Identity] // Dataset
```

[image]

**Update** thanks to **RunnyKines** comment:

```
Dataset @ Counts @ n
```

does the same job more elegantly

Comment: I know this question is a duplicate but you can use `Counts` instead i.e. `Dataset @ Counts @ n`